# Python Comparing columns of 2 csv files and writing to a new csv

Tags: python, csv, compare

I have 2 csv files each with only 1 column as below:

**csv file 1 : adam3us.csv**

```
created_at
6/7/2018 19:00
6/6/2018 12:00
6/6/2018 9:00
6/6/2018 9:00
6/6/2018 5:00
6/5/2018 16:00
6/5/2018 7:00
6/4/2018 16:00
```

**csv file 2 : Bitcoin Hourly Based**

```
created_at
1/8/2017 0:00
1/8/2017 1:00
1/8/2017 2:00
1/8/2017 3:00
1/8/2017 4:00
1/8/2017 5:00
1/8/2017 6:00
6/7/2018 19:00
```

I am trying to write a python script that will compare each value of the csv file 2 with every entry in the csv file 1 using a loop and if the entries match, should increment a declared variable called count and then should write to a new csv file, with one column created_at containing the time that is same for both csv files and a second column with the value of count.

For example, the 1st iteration will take the 1st row of csv file 2, i.e. 6/7/2018 19:00 and compare its value with every row present in the csv file 1. If the 1st row of the csv file 2 matches any row of csv file 1 then count variable should be incremented. In this case it will match the 1st row of the csv file 2 with the last row of the csv file 1 and would increment count from 0 to 1 and would write the value of created_at and the value of count to new separate csv file called output. The output file for this example should look like as below :

**output.csv**

```
created_at        count
6/7/2018 19:00      1
```

The count variable should be set to 0 for every iteration and the process should repeat for every iteration.

My code that I have is as below :

```
 import csv

 count=0

path1 = r'C:\Users\Ahmed Ismail Khalid\Desktop\Bullcrap Testing Delete Later\Bitcoin Prices Hourly Based.csv'
path2 = r'C:\Users\Ahmed Ismail Khalid\Desktop\Bullcrap Testing Delete Later\adam3us.csv'
path3 = r'C:\Users\Ahmed Ismail Khalid\Desktop\output.csv'



with open(path1,'rt',encoding='utf-8') as csvin:
reader1 = csv.reader(csvin)
for row in reader1:
    b=row[0]
    with open(path2,'rt',encoding='utf-8') as csvinpu:
        with open(path3, 'w', newline='',encoding='utf-8') as csvoutput:
            writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
            reader2 = csv.reader(csvinpu)
            all = []
            row = next(reader2)
            row.append('count')
            all.append(row)
            for row in reader2:
               d=row[0]
               if(b==d) :
                   count+=1
                   row.append(count)
                   all.append(row)
               else:
                   row.append(count)
                   all.append(row)
                   writer.writerows(all)
```

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) for such manipulations.

Load both csv file in two data-frame using pandas and take the intersection of both column. Pandas have inbuilt features.
[pd.merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
Import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1)
df2 = pd.read_csv(file2)
output = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="inner", on="column_name") #column_name should be common in both dataframe
#how represents type of intersection. In your case it will be inner(INNER JOIN)
output['count'] = output.groupby('column_name')['column_name'].transform('size') #pandas query
final_output = output.drop_duplicates() #It will remove duplicate rows
```

Hope, It will help.

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks. But how can I increment the count variable with this? Help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: I have edited the answer. I hope, it will solve your problem.