# How to compare two CSV files and print the differences/write to a new CSV file

Tags: python-2.7, csv, comparison

I am working on a python code to execute on my firewall. I am not an expert programmer but love to learn. I have gone through many posts that are related to comparing two CSV files using python and write the differences to new csv file but none of them are promising. because the requirement I have is I have two csv files with around 500 row/500 entries. I need to compare each entry with all other entries in 2nd csv file if that entry is not found in the 2nd csv file I need to write that to a new csv file. so, it's basically not a line to line comparison. Does this even possible, could you please help me if you have already gone through that.

Many thanks in advance. 
any input is much appreciated.

Regards, Nagarjuna

gone through the python code for two csv files comparison.

```
with open('citrixdata1.csv','r') as f_left:
    reader_left = csv.reader(f_left, delimiter=',')
    with open('ActiveCitrix.csv','r') as f_right:
        reader_right = csv.reader(f_right, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader_left:
            for compare_row in reader_right:
                if row == compare_row:
                    print(row,'is equal to',compare_row)
                else:
                    print(row,'is not equal to',compare_row)
                    with open('output.csv', 'w') as outFile:
                        f_right.seek(0)
```

the above code repeatedly printing only one entry with 'some x' is equal to 'x'. so, it's kind of doing infinite loop at first entry and not going through the other entries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Comparing columns of 2 csv files and writing to a new csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50785498/python-comparing-columns-of-2-csv-files-and-writing-to-a-new-csv)